# docker-compose doesn't detect .env file with -f option

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using a makefile to build my project and this is my file hierarchy:

```
➜  Inception git:(main) ✗ ls -l *
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcavalei dcavalei  258 Jan  6 16:34 Makefile

srcs:
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 5 dcavalei dcavalei 4096 Jan  6 11:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 dcavalei dcavalei 4096 Jan  6 17:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcavalei dcavalei  631 Jan  6 17:02 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 dcavalei dcavalei  123 Jan  6 15:49 .env
drwxr-xr-x 3 dcavalei dcavalei 4096 Jan  6 11:23 mariadb
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcavalei dcavalei 4096 Jan  6 11:45 nginx
drwxr-xr-x 2 dcavalei dcavalei 4096 Jan  5 15:21 wordpress
```

basically when i type `docker-compose up` inside `srcs` dir, it works as expected, but
if i try:

- `docker-compose -f ./srcs/docker-compose.yml up` when i'm at my project root, it does not read my `.env` file

I get the following warning:

```sh
➜  Inception git:(main) ✗ docker-compose -f ./srcs/docker-compose.yml up
WARNING: The MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_USER variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_PASSWORD variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The MYSQL_WP_NAME variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some old docker-compose, e.g. `docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064`. The compose will set `project-directory` as the current folder which run the `docker-compose`. The behavior changes start `+v1.28`.

So, for you, you have 3 options, you can choose any one.

1. Upgrade `docker-compose` to `+v1.28` or latest.
2. Move `.env` to the folder which you run `docker-compose`
3. Use `--project-directory` to force an alternate working directory, like next:

**docker/docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

**docker/.env:**

```
TAG=3
```

**execution:**

```
$ ls
docker
$ docker-compose --project-directory docker -f docker/docker-compose.yaml config
services:
  web:
    image: webapp:3
version: '3.0'
```

Comment: 1. Upgrade docker-compose to +v1.28 or latest.
it worked perfectly, thank you @atline